# LDA alpha equivalent in structural topic model

Tags: prior, dirichlet-distribution, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I'm using an implementation of the structural topic model (stm), written in R using the `stm` package.

I want to reduce the number of topics that are prevalent in each document. In an LDA I would reduce the alpha parameter.

I understand that the stm and LDA make different distributional assumptions, but is there an stm equivalent to the alpha parameter in an LDA?

I'd also find it useful, if an equivalent doesn't exist, a short explanation why!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent is `gamma.prior` in `stm()`. There are two options of `gamma.prior`: `Pooled` and `L1`. `Pooled` (the default option) is a zero-mean normal prior, but it does not induce sparsity, while `L1` induces sparsity. If you want to have more control, you can also invoke the `control` argument.

For a more detailed description, please read the 5.1 of the [vignette](https://www.structuraltopicmodel.com/) of `stm`.